# How to copy many tables from one database to another database using pgAdmin4 on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I just created a new database. I want to bring existing Tables from old Database to the new one for database clean up purpose. I am looking for a short cut than doing it manually. I'm using pgAdmin4 tool on PostgreSQL.

Comment: I recommend using the `pg_dump` tool instead. It is written just for that purpose.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I appreciate the insight! I will take your recommendation. :)

Comment: There is no "pgAdmin6". You may be thinking of  pgAdmin4 v6.xx. It just provides a GUI on top of `pg_dump`, `pg_dumpall`, and `pg_restore` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed that typo. @ErwinBrandstetter